# C++ linker error

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++ and need some help with namespaces.
Following are my 4 files:

```
node.h <--class interface
node.cpp <--implementation
testNodeFunctions.cpp 
testNodeMain.cpp

//node.h
---------------------------------
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

namespace namespaceName{

    class Node {
    private:
        int data;

    public:
        void setData( int x);
        int getData();

    };
   //and some more functions

}

//node.cpp
-------------------------------------
#include <iostream>
#include "node.h"
using namespace std;

namespace namespaceName {
      //provides implementation of the memeber functions
     int Node::getData() const{
       return data;
     }
     void Node::setData(int x){
     data=x;
     }

}//namespace


//testNodeFunctions.cpp 
-------------------------------------
#include <iostream>
#include "Node.h"
using namespace std;
using namespace namespaceName;

void showData(){
  //creates a Node object and prints some stuff
  Node a=37;
  cout<<a.getValue()<<endl;
}


//testNodeMain.cpp
----------------------------------------------
#include <iostream>
#include "Node.h"

void showData();

int main(){
//calls methods from testNodeFunctions
showData();
}
```

I'm not sure if I'm defining the namespace currently.

How Do I call the showData() function from the testNodeMain.cpp file. Currently I'm getting linker error stating that "undefined reference to namespaceName::Node::methodname"

Thanks so much in advance

Okay. That make sense. I removed , using namespace std from header. I'm compiling the testNodeMain.cpp which has the main(). the TestNodeMain.cpp calls functions from testNodeFunctions.cpp. testNodeFunctions.cpp creates Node object.

Comment: Never put `using namespace ...` in a header file. Come to that, why do you even have `#include <iostream>` in your header ?

Comment: please show the relevant code and your build commands. there are two possibilities: your code (which you don't show) is wrong, or, your build commands (which you don't show) are wrong. by the way, don't have `using namespace std;` in the global namespace in a header, that's Evil, and preferably don't include `<iostream>` in a header (e.g. instead include `<iosfwd>`).

Comment: Can you include some more details on how you're compiling? You're including the node.h header, but are you compiling all three .cxx files together?

Comment: Okay. That make sense. I removed <iostream>, using namespace std from header. I'm compiling the testNodeMain.cpp which has the main(). the TestNodeMain.cpp calls functions from testNodeFunctions.cpp.  testNodeFunctions.cpp creates Node object.

Comment: @user491753: you're still not showing the relevant code, and you're still not showing your build commands. so essentially you're saying, help, when i try to heat some soup it's still cold, doesn't work!, can you tell me what's wrong from this pic of the soup box?

Comment: If you are building a separate object file for node and for testNodeFunctions, be sure to include them when linking testNodeMain.

Comment: It would help if you copy/paste the exact code you're trying to build, rather than copying it by hand. It's hard to tell whether the mistakes in the code that you keep fixing are related to the problem, or just transcription errors. You currently have a `const` on the definition of `getData()`, but not the declaration; that's wrong, but would not cause the error you're reporting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your header file node.h, you have

```
    void setData( int x);
    int getData();
```

where as in your node.cpp file, you have:

```
 int Node::getValue() const{
   return data;
 }
 void Node::setValue(int x){
 data=x;
 }
```

You need to change your `Node::getValue() const {}` to `Node::getData() const {}`, or change the names of the functions in your header files to `int getValue()` and `void setValue (int x)`

The function names in the header files for the class and the actual .cpp file should be the same.

Answer (score 0):

It's really hard to tell without a complete compiling example that induces your problem, but it looks like you forgot to include `node.cpp` on your link line.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not sure what you meant by link line, I'm new to C++. This is a homework problem, I don't want to post all my code here since it shows up in search results.

Comment: So node.h and node.cpp are inside namespaceName. TestNodeFunctions creates a Node object and creates a function calld showData() which calls functions from Node.cpp to print stuff. and finllay the TestNodeMain calls the showData()

Answer (score 0):

> I'm not sure if I'm defining the namespace currently.

That looks fine, although without seeing what you've put inside it I can't say for sure.

> How Do I call the showData() function from the testNodeMain.cpp file?

The function needs to be *declared* before you can call it. Add the following declaration, either after the `#include` lines in `testNodeMain.cpp`, or in another header file which must then be included from `testNodeMain.cpp`:

```
void showData();
```

Then you can call the function from `main`:

```
int main() {
    showData();
}
```

> Currently I'm getting linker error stating that "undefined reference to namespaceName::Node::methodname"

You need to make sure you're compiling and linking all the source files, not just the main one. If you're using GCC, the build command should look something like:

```
gcc -o testNode testNodeMain.cpp testNodeFunctions.cpp node.cpp
```

If you're still getting the error in that case, then check that you have actually implemented the methods. If you think you have, then please update the code in your question to include the implementation of one of the missing methods so we can check that for you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I had no idea that I will have to use command line. I'm using Dev-C++ IDE. How do I use command line from there?

Comment: @user491753: You shouldn't need to use the command line if you're using an IDE; just make sure all the source files are included in your project. I'm afraid I'm not familiar with that IDE, so I can't help with that. It might help if you post the complete output when you try to build it, if the IDE gives you more than just the error message.

Comment: thanks so much for your help. I just had to include the files. Now how do I accept your answer in this forum?

Comment: @user491753: There should be a checkbox next to the question, I think. I'm not sure, as I've never asked a question myself.

Comment: @user491753 Just click the little hollow checkbox next to his answer and it'll light up.